# Passing ChromeCast Google Drive Media File

Tags: android, ios, google-drive-api, chromecast, google-cast

How can I pass ChromeCast a Google Drive File

According to the Drive Docs https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<myFileID>?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

However the initializer for Chromecast does not allow me to pass headers.

```
* @param contentID The content ID.
* @param streamType The stream type.
* @param contentType The content (MIME) type.
* @param metadata The media item metadata.
* @param streamDuration The stream duration.
* @param mediaTracks The media tracks, if any, otherwise <code>nil</code>.
* @param textTrackStyle The text track style, if any, otherwise <code>nil</code>.
* @param customData The custom application-specific data.
*/
- (instancetype)initWithContentID:(NSString *)contentID
                       streamType:(GCKMediaStreamType)streamType
                      contentType:(NSString *)contentType
                         metadata:(GCKMediaMetadata *)metadata
                   streamDuration:(NSTimeInterval)streamDuration
                      mediaTracks:(NSArray *)mediaTracks
                   textTrackStyle:(GCKMediaTextTrackStyle *)textTrackStyle
                       customData:(id)customData;
```

I have tried passing the **refresh** token as &**access_token**=%@ but it does not seem to accept this for Google Drive

Comment: What type of drive file are you trying to pass to your chromecast?

Comment: Photos, Video and Music. Eventually at the moment I have tried just photos

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using the ***GTLDriveFile.downloadUrl*** and the **Access Token** but not using the ***alt=media*** download format

I added the **&access_token="ya29.fffff"** to the downloadURL , not the refresh token.

Getting my hands on the access token is non trivial since the Google Api obfuscates it but that is different issue

This is my URL which ChromeCast accepted

```
url:https://doc-0o-8s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/6jbbjm36tl2vvbnepiqedkpbkuhg3r98/v71obao5sam6d833fitiouc32bvcrkmg/1442390400000/00092883636123010676/00092883636123010676/0B-X-qhbL0RO4SWl5V3Y2VjFsZlE?e=download&gd=true&access_token=ya29.8AGXvMuvxRa9X3xLLUZdJTqMS_rHRstXMLgmBhMY_90ti4hC50540y4G-qOutfbDpO
```